# How to force IRuleBuilder in AbstractValidator to act as 'if' statement?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

This is my code:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Content).NotEmpty().Must(content => content.Trim().Length > 0);
```

I expect it should behave as

```
if (NotEmpty(x.Content) && x.Content.Trim().Length > 0)
```

statement but it throws `NullReferenceException` if `x.Content` is `null`.

Please help me with a workaround.

Comment: Show your full code.. You can read [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: @SonerGönül I am about 5 years with C#, so... thanks))

Comment: well I guess `NotEmpty(x.Content)` will also throw an exception if `x.Content == null` so you will ne to check for that

Comment: @derape Yes, but it would be ValidationException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this code works perfectly too:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Content)   
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)    
        .NotEmpty()   
        .Must(content => content.Trim().Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [`Unless`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless) which allows you to execute a rule based on a condition. You need to split up your rule into two, however:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Content).NotEmpty();
RuleFor(x => x.Content).Must(content => content.Trim().Length > 0).Unless(x => x == null);
```

Or you could use the `??` operator, which is even more compact:

```
RuleFor(x => (x.Content ?? "").Trim()).NotEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [custom rule](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom). If the rule returns true, then create a `ValidationFailure`. Something like this:

```
public class ViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ViewModel>
{
    public ViewModelValidator()
    {
        Custom(r => ContentIsEmpty(r) ? new ValidationFailure("Content", "Content must not be empty.") : null);
    }

    private static bool ContentIsEmpty(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Content);
    }
}
```